# Javascript for loop stuck on i = 2?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript for loop and it keeps getting stuck on i = 2

```
 var i;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < $('ul#questions span').length + 1; i++){
  console.log("i",i)
  var id = document.getElementById(i);
  if(i = count){
    $( id ).show();
  }else{
    $( id ).hide();
  }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: `if(i = count)` is the problem. Change it to `if (i === count)`

Comment: You want to compare the value, but you're assigning it.

Comment: That's a lot of duplicate answers for a typo question.

Comment: Read about the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Assignment_operators) and the [equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Equality_operators) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

replace **i = count** to **i == count**

```
 var i;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < $('ul#questions span').length + 1; i++){
  console.log("i",i)
  var id = document.getElementById(i);
  if(i == count){
    $( id ).show();
  }else{
    $( id ).hide();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing a comparison, you are assigning `i` inside of the loop, preventing it from incrementing properly.

```js
var i;

for ( i = 0 ; i < $('ul#questions span').length + 1; i++) {
  console.log("i",i)

  var id = document.getElementById(i);

  if (i == count) { // Comparison instead of assignment
    $( id ).show();
  } else {
    $( id ).hide();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (i = count)` means "if assignment of `count` to `i` succeeds do..."

To avoid that endless loop you should change it to `if (i == count)` to make your condition "if `count` is equal to `i` do..."